# Не выводится изменённая переменная

Tags: javascript, html

есть DIV элемент у которого есть атрибут onclick вызывающий эту функцию

```
function addMoney() {
moneyNum += moneyAdding;
moneyDiv.innerHTML = moneyNum;}
```

в третьей строке этой функции прописана "замена" прошлого значения и написание нового, но этого не происходит. Почему? В коде до этой функции уже есть:

```
var moneyNum = 0;
moneyDiv.innerHTML = moneyNum;
```

Этот ноль выводится, а новое число нет. Что делать подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да вроде все работает:

```js
let moneyDiv = document.querySelector('div');
let moneyNum =0;
let moneyToAdd = 10;
moneyDiv.onclick = addMoney;

function addMoney() {
moneyNum += moneyToAdd;
moneyDiv.innerHTML = moneyNum;
}
```

```html
<div>0</div>
```